# Calling a jQuery function on MouseOver and MouseOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have the following code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js" type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('.webPanel').mouseover(function(){
        $('.webPanel').animate({'width': '350px'}, 100);

      });
  });
</script>
```

Which doesn't work. As you could probably tell, it's supposed to expand the .webPanel div to 350px on mouseover, but nothing happens.

How can I get this thing to work? I don't understand why it isn't working!

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a separate script inclusion for jquery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('.webPanel').mouseover(function(){
        $('.webPanel').animate({'width': '350px'}, 100);

      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: A note for the others (took me more than a few secs what the difference was!), @Darin has opened and closed the script tags properly

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    //you script
</script>
```

And how about hover function

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

  $(function() {
    $('.webPanel').hover(
        function(){
        $('.webPanel').animate({'width': '350px'}, 100);
    },
    function (){
        $('.webPanel').animate({'width': '500px'}, 100);
    }

      });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote your script in jsfiddle and it works great.
Please, see the [code here](http://jsfiddle.net/3mxWm/).

I think that your problem is due to the code you wrote between the script tags.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

your function need to be in separate script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">           // this missing
  $(function() {
    $('.webPanel').mouseover(function(){
       $('.webPanel').animate({'width': '350px'}, 100);
    });
  });
</script>                                 // this missing
```